# building an em fx forward curve with forward spreads

Tags: fx, yield-curve

Like the title suggests, I'm trying to build a forward curve for exchange rates in USD/em currencies. I have certain forward points already, but they're in spreads and ideally, I'd like to construct this curve without using a spot rate. My initial idea was to use the points that I do have and perform a linear interpolation, which works perfect for anything past one week. Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a way to accurately calculate the forward mid-points from spot (without using the spot rate) to 1w.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a spot rate when the convention is to quote in forward points?

Comment: What exactly does the sentence "compute from spot without using spot" mean?

Comment: Why don't you post the data that you have and state what you are explicitly doing with it and what you hope to yield..

Comment: If the FX currency is liquid enough, you could try using OIS/deposit rates to figure out forward rate using covered interest parity. Not sure if that's what your after or not.